# I want to recover data from encrypted hard disk after failed ubuntu release upgrade

Tags: luks

I had an encrypted ubuntu 18.04 and i tried a release upgrade which failed and now the system cannot boot.
I have reinstalled ubuntu on another disk and now i am trying to mount the old encrypted partition but something is wrong.
The old hard disk is showing the following partitions:

[image]
[image]

I can do luksOpen with passphrase but nothing more.
If i try to mount:

## mount /dev/mapper/sdg5 /merda

```
mount: /merda: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/sdg5, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

lvdisplay shows only the current OS volume

lsblk shows:
sdg                                             8:96   0 931,5G  0 disk
├─sdg1                                          8:97   0   487M  0 part
├─sdg2                                          8:98   0     1K  0 part
└─sdg5                                          8:101  0   931G  0 part
└─sdg5                                      253:6    0   931G  0 crypt

Can you help, i have no knowledge about this topic.

Comment: When you luksOpen an encrypted volume you must get a new volume in `/dev/mapper` to work with. Could you show your exact luksOpen command?

Comment: $ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdf5 sdf5
Enter passphrase for /dev/sdf5: 
$ 
(sdx changed after reboot)

Comment: Could you give it a different name? E.g. `sudo luksOpen /dev/sdf5 MyVolume`? And then run `sudo file -s /dev/mapper/MyVolume`? Of course you need to `luksClose` or reboot first.

Comment: $ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdf5 MyVolume
Enter passphrase for /dev/sdf5: 
$ sudo file -s /dev/mapper/MyVolume
/dev/mapper/MyVolume: symbolic link to ../dm-5
$ sudo file -s /dev/dm-5
/dev/dm-5: data
$ ls -al /dev/mapper/MyVolume
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 gen  8 18:00 /dev/mapper/MyVolume -> ../dm-5
$

Comment: `sudo file -s /dev/dm-5 /dev/dm-5: data` -> this doesn't look good. For a valid FS `file -s` should produce a valid output, e.g. `/dev/sda2: Linux rev 1.0 ext2 filesystem data, UUID=[redacted] (extents) (large files)`

Comment: I wonder how it could have lost the data you are showing since it was just a failed release upgrade. Ok it wont boot but at least the data should be accessible from an external os.

Comment: Yeah, it should show the previous data.I've no idea what happened on your system.

Comment: You could try the `testdisk` partition recovery tool on /dev/mapper/... to see if it can find something somewhere.

Comment: Disk /dev/mapper/MyVolume - 999 GB / 931 GiB - 1952489472 sectors
Current partition structure:
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors
Partition sector doesn't have the endmark 0xAA55 analysis gives nothing